# iOS "Private"/AdHoc App Store - principle of operation

Tags: ios, app-store, iosdeployment

How do the "private" app stores operate from a technological point of view?

For example, this store used in Iran: http://sibapp.com/

My questions are:

1. Do they require jailbreak?
2. How the apps are distributed, compared to the standard App Store.

Comment: You can select specific territory while distributing application. or you can use Mobile Device Management ex. Air-watch.

Comment: Could you elaborate on it? What kind of distribution profile do they use? Ad-Hoc? Enterprise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enrol Apple Enterprise distribution program and create distribution certificate to create private environment. Apple also provide own environment or you can use third party ex. Air-Watch. Refer([Air-Watch](https://www.air-watch.com/solutions/mobile-device-management/))